# Looping over an array's indexes to populate ng-options' choices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, ng-options

Hey guys I'm struggling trying to loop over `productData.colors_and_sizes.data[i].sizes` collection to put them into a single `ng-option` drop down.

The data set is straight forward but i've only used `ng-option` inside an array of strings.

[image]

### **Question:**

Is it possible to loop over the `productData.colors_and_sizes.data[x].sizes` w/o transforming the data into an array of strings?  I feel I just need to count over `[i]` but I dunno how :c

**Html:**

*loop over `productData.colors_and_sizes.data[i].sizes`*

```
   <select ng-model="item.mySize" ng-options="choice as choice for choice in productData.colors_and_sizes.data[i].sizes">
       <option value="">Please select a size</option>
   </select>
```

in the end, the values will be: `Twin, Full, Queen, King`.

Comment: Can you please add a plunker for the same ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option ng-repeat="opt in options" value="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.text}}</option>
```

that sort of thing should do it in general. So then the trick is getting your data in there. Assuming you're just using strings, it could be

```
<option ng-repeat="item in productData.colors_and_sizes.data" value="{{item.sizes}}">{{item.sizes}}</option>
```

It's a little weird to name the field 'sizes' when it seems to be a singular resource ("Twin" rather than ["Twin", "Full"...]), but as long as sizes is just a string, you can access it like the above.

Comment: Yeah it's super weird... it's jsut how the damn data is coming in.  it's so deeply nested and dependent on staying pristine that transforming it would be such a headache.  Regardless, this works ad intended.  Thanks will mark correct ASAP.

Comment: Do you know if the ng-model='item.mySize" will work this way?  item is being ng-init="item = this" in the parent?

Comment: I generally avoid mucking around with `this` in html stuff in angular, as most angular expressions end up getting attached to $scope at some point or another (so `item = this` may well end up interpreted as `scope.item = scope.this`, which isn't really what you want). Personally, I would tend toward setting up the mySize and other variables in a controller; it looks like you're getting the data in async anyway, so $http.get(/* data */).then(function(data){ $scope.mySizes = stuff; $scope.items = parseThatData(data);}) and so on.